# Laravel 5.5 MSSQL 2005 Column with accented letters

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to get data from an existent MSSQL 2005 database using laravel 5.5 (environment: Windows, XAMPP and PHP7).
I have a table called "Clienti" that has diffrent columns in Italian language with accents inside the names (i.e. Città, ModalitàDiPagamento and so on).
Every time I try to retrieve the data with my model including theese fields in the select statement an exception occours:

```
"Error encoding model [App\Company] with ID [1] to JSON: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded"
```

But when I exclude theese fields everything work properly.

My model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Company extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Clienti';
    protected $primaryKey = 'ID';
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

The query:

```
$company = Company::where('ID',1)->firstOrFail();
return $company;
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

I've found a solution that fixes the issue:

```
public function newFromBuilder($attributes = [], $connection = null)
{
    $model = $this->newInstance([], true);

    $model->setRawAttributes((array) $attributes, true);

    $model->hidden = [];

    $model->setConnection($connection ?: $this->getConnectionName());

    $model->fireModelEvent('retrieved', false);

    return $model;
}

public function setRawAttributes(array $attributes, $sync = false)
{
    foreach($attributes as $key => $value)
    {   
        if(!mb_check_encoding($key,'UTF-8')){
            $newkey = utf8_encode($key);
            $attributes[$newkey] = $value;
            unset($attributes[$key]);
        }
    }

    $this->attributes = $attributes;
    if ($sync) {
        $this->syncOriginal();
    }

    return $this;
}
```

You only need to import theese methods inside the model class.

Comment: Try forcing UTF8 encoding on your existing database?

Comment: I don't know if this is possible in MSSQL 2005

Comment: if that is not possible, export the database to a system where it is possible e.g. mysql?

Comment: No, I can't move the DB from the original server because it's shared with other apps that uses stored procedure in mssql.

Comment: Thanks to all. I've updated the message. Check for the solution.

Comment: Hi @tiziano, how you connect laravel + MSSQL 2005 ? Thank you